# How to Variable Cache in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am looking at trying to cache variables in PHP from a JSON file. Is there anyone that knows of a good tutorial or can provide an example?

Comment: Persistent caching (saves between page loads), or only during the page load?

Comment: Multiple JSON data requests to a remote server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save variable to file cache:

```
file_put_contents('cache.txt', json_encode($variable));
```

Read cache into variable:

```
$variable = json_decode(file_get_contents('cache.txt'));
```

Comment: So before this Dan, do I need to create an area for the file to be written too? and do you know a good way to set an expiry to the variable if there were changes to the remote server

Comment: Like sweep up a corner in your house and put a hard drive there? ;) No, it's fine, the computer will save the file to the same directory as the PHP script. You can do an expiration by comparing `time()` (the current time) to `filemtime('cache.txt')` (the modification time of the file).

Answer (score 1):

Memcached is your best bet.  It will save any serializable data in a very fast cache. You can find a tutorial at:

http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.examples-overview.php

It is lightning quick and has many other features that makes it better than just saving a txt file to the server.

```
$memcache->set('key', $jsonstring, false, 10)
```

and

```
$get_result = $memcache->get('key');
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is:

```
function getMyJson()
{
    $data = apc_fetch('my_json', $wasCached);
    if ($wasCached) {
        return $data;
    }
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/data.json'));
    apc_store('my_json', $data);
    return $data;
}
```

This uses APC's cache but you could work similarly with memcached, redis etc.